# TikZ relative coordinate system

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates, relative

When I use the command below:

```
\draw (apex)+(1mm,0) -- node {$h$} (center)+(1mm,0);
```

where `(apex)` and `(center)` is predefined appropriately, then I have a problem where `+(1mm, 0)` is not applied to the `(center)` although it is applied well to `(apex)`. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please make your code compilable next time! How should we know what you consider `appropriate predefinitions`? To answer this, people either have to create a minimal example, because you didn't provide one, or post without testing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line is first drawn to `(center)`, then `+(1mm,0)` causes a move-to operation to the right by 1 mm.

TikZ library `calc` helps:

```
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\draw (apex) +(1mm, 0) -- node {$h$} ($(center) + (1mm, 0)$);
% or
\draw ($(apex) + (1mm, 0)$) -- node {$h$} ($(center) + (1mm, 0)$);
```

Also a solution without library `calc` is possible, e.g. by using a temporary coordinate:

```
\draw (center) +(1mm, 0) coordinate (tmp)
      (apex) +(1mm, 0) -- node {$h$} (tmp);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `shift` option for the coordinates.

```
\draw ([shift={(1mm,0)}]apex) -- node {$h$} ([shift={(1mm,0)}]center);
```

or

```
\draw ([xshift=1mm]apex) -- node {$h$} ([xshift=1mm]center);
```